# XPS Document with Print Ticket not printing correctly

Tags: .net, xps

I am trying to print XPS files, created in .Net, to several different makes of printer.

I have written some code to create the XPS and print it via PrintDialog along with a document level print ticket and this works correctly.  However the document I want to create needs to be laid out as follows:

- Page 1 and 2 printed in duplex
- Page 3 and 4 printed in simplex
- The whole document needs stapling.

At the moment I can create an XPS file that contains all the pages.  However I have to duplex all the pages (blank pages after 3 and 4) as the printer ignores the individual page level print tickets.

What I want to do is create 2 separate documents each with their own print tickets that specify duplexing and then combine these into another XPS document that contains a document level print ticket that staples the output.

Although I can create this document the printer ignores the document print tickets and just prints all the pages out.

The printers I am currently testing with are an HP CM4730 MFP and a Kyocera FS-2020D.

Does anyone have any ideas/code examples that will solve this.

Comment: I'm having a very similar issue. Printing to a printer with an XPS based driver does work but a PostScript based printer doesn't. My guess is this is as much as MS have implemented despite what the docs imply.